# Error occurs in select clause querying for technical analysis module in DolphinDB

Tags: select, initialization, dolphindb

The picture shows the table schema:
[image]

The line reported an error when querying the data:

```
select *,bBands(close, 5, 2, 2, 0) as `high`mid`low  from kline
```

The error message is:

```
The calculated column was not initialized or an exception was raised.
```

However, another script I tried didn't report the error:

```
close = 7.2 6.97 7.08 6.74 6.49 5.9 6.26 5.9 5.35 5.63 3.81 3.935 4.04 3.74 3.7 3.33 3.64 3.31 2.69 2.72
date = (2020.03.02 + 0..4 join 7..11).take(20)
symbol = take(`F,10) join take(`GPRO,10)
t = table(symbol, date, close) 
select *, bBands(close, 5, 2, 2, 2) as `high`mid`low from t context by symbol
```

Why the error occurs and how can I avoid it in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is raised because the names of the columns coincide with UP and DN of the Bollinger Bands.

You can use the following code:

```
select *,bBands(close, 5, 2, 2, 0) as `bBand_high`mid`bBand_low  from kline.
```